# ODBC connection through Flyway

Tags: java, maven-plugin, flyway

I am trying to use maven/flyway for database versioning through ODBC.

I am using sql server localdb as the database. But I am getting the following error when I don't give a userid/password when I run mvn flyway:status:

> Flyway Error: com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException:
>   Database username missing. It was not specified as a property and it
>   was not defined in settings.xml for the server with the id 'flyway-db'

And when I give the empty username/password, it shows:

> Flyway Error: com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException:
>   Database username missing. It was not specified as a property and it
>   was not defined in settings.xml for the server with the id 'flyway-db'
>   -> [Help 1]

My database does not have a userid/password. Following is the configuration tag I am using(in case of empty userid/password):

```
        <configuration>
            <driver>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:odbc:localdbtest</url>
            <user></user>
            <password></password>
        </configuration>
```

I believe for empty username/password, there is something else that needs to be done. 
Not sure. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your situation is similar to [Issue 341](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=341). I'll look into this for the next release.

**Update:** This should be fixed now in Flyway 2.0